# How to make category with property and value

Tags: mediawiki-extensions

I want to create a page with a catergory Actor, property:located in and value height :180 using semantic media wiki API . I want to query the same using parser function. The sample example may be like [image] I have #ask SMW extension for that. i got the result using #ask. I need to do the same using SMW . can some one kindly help me with this. This is the statement i used to query in parser function.

```
  $this->wgOut->addHTML('<h2>{{#ask: [[Category:Actor]] | ?located in| ?height}} </h2>');
```

Answer (score 0):

What, `$this->wgOut->addHTML`? O_o Please don't hack PHP files.

Just edit a wiki page and add your #ask syntax in it. You can first visit Special:Ask to tweak your query, then click "embed code" to get the syntax you need to post in the wiki page. From my understanding of your question, it's probably something like:

```
{{#ask: [[Category:Actor]] [[height::180]] | ?located in| ?height}}
```

Comment: yes man, i edited the page using that #ask query and i got the result. Actually i needed to perform it using a SMW extension or a php class to get the pages displayed programatically.